# How can I read this entire comment on Stack Exchange?

Tags: discussion, comments

This comment, I want to read it in full: 
*[R error in glmnet: NA/NaN/Inf in foreign function call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21858124/r-error-in-glmnet-na-nan-inf-in-foreign-function-call?answertab=active#comment39328353_21864553)*

The comment begins and ends like this: "A few different solutions exist: [...] 4) use a package that can handle NA values, for example, ada –"

That can't be the end of the comment, right?!

I've tried clicking everywhere on the comment and the page. I've tried to see if I could find anything on the commenter's page, or if I could message him somehow https://stackoverflow.com/users/2636317/mgoldwasser. I've tried checking if there is an R package called "ada". So far, no luck!

What should I do?

Comment: That's probably already the complete comment. Comments have a [maximum length of 600 characters](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19757).

Comment: Humans rarely do things like leave incom

Comment: @JeanneDark nope. There's 177 remaining. https://i.stack.imgur.com/PMFWd.jpg The formatting of the comment (stripped when posted) shows a nice numbered list.

Comment: The poster most likely hit enter when creating that list, and posted the comment. Maybe we should remove that Enter shortcut and add a different one - Shift-Enter? Meta (Cmd/Ctrl)-Enter?

Answer (score 4):

I pulled open the inspector on the page and that is all that is loaded into the browser.[image]

I did google "Ada R" and found this: https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/ada/versions/2.0-5/topics/ada

Looks like that package might be able to handle NA values which is why he referenced it. The commenter either didn't finish his comment or just didn't clearly end his statement.